# how do you ask for someones name on the other side of the call without sounding rude?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, resume, career-development, recruitment

how to ask for peoples names without sounding rude

Comment: This question needs much more info, please [edit] it. Especially: *Why* do you want to ask their name? You are asking this on an international forum and telephone customs differ from country to country (so tell us yours): in Italy people will answer with 'Pronto', in The Netherlands people will answer with their name.

Comment: There is no universally applicable answer beyond "just ask them and don't be rude". VTC as too broad.

Comment: "Can I ask who's calling?"

Answer (score 5):

"I'm sorry, your name is...?"

"Can I say who is calling?"

"Sorry, I missed your name..."

Make it sound like your mistake and it becomes fine.

Comment: Or 'Can I have your name please', just put a 'please' on the end and it's all good.